# Validating Radio based on rows for matrix type jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 1.0.

I have this Code

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td> <input type="radio" id="r11"   value="a" name="r1_selectedobjects" /> </td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r12"   value="b" name="r1_selectedobjects" /> <td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r21"   value="a" name="r2_selectedobjects" /></td>
  <input type="radio" id="r22"   value="b" name="r2_selectedobjects" /></td>
</tr>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r31"   value="a" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
   <td><input type="radio" id="r32"   value="b" name="r3_selectedobjects" /></td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" id="matbutton" data-inline="true"  value="Submit" onclick="return CheckMatrixRadio(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

so when i click on the submit button i should validate that in every row the value should be selected. I have written this script.

```
function CheckMatrixRadio(button) { 
var totalvalues ='';
        $('input[name$=_selectedobjects]:checked').each(function () { 
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    totalvalues += $(this).val() + ',';
                }
                else { 
                    alert('Can not leave empty');
                } 
        });
  }
```

but its not working properly(not considering row wise). How should i validate that in Jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the `:checked` selector, which is only selecting the inputs which are checked...

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
var all_checkd = true;
var totalvalues ='';

$('tr:not(:eq(3))').each(function(index){


       if($(this).find('input[name*="_selectedobjects"]').is(':checked'))
       {
          totalvalues += $(this).find('input[name*="_selectedobjects"]:checked').val() +',';
       }
       else
       {
         all_checkd = false;
       }
});

if(all_checkd )
 {
    //do the work
}
```

Comment: `$(':radio')` returns 6 elements, so it won't work. You can select 3 top.

Comment: @ Lolo . nop . you can not check two radio buttons with same name ;)

Answer (score 0):

It can't work. First of all you select only checked elements, secondly `val()` returns value of the radio button, not checked state. Try this:

```
function CheckMatrixRadio(button) { 
    var totalvalues ='';
    var checked = $('input[name$=_selectedobjects]:checked');

    var count = 0;
    var map = {};
    $('input[name$=_selectedobjects]').each(function() { 
        if (!map[this.name]) {
            map[this.name] = true;
            count++;
        }
    });

    if (checked.length < count) {
        alert('Can not leave empty');
        return false;
    }

    checked.each(function () { 
        totalvalues += $(this).val() + ',';
    });

    return true;
}
```